# How do I use a group element to remove the previous input?

Tags: javascript, grouping

The code I have been working on will take a user input and create an ellipse with certain vectors drawn on it. I have already successfully coded the ability for the program to receive new input, delete the old ellipse and show the new one. My problem is that I now need to do that with all of my vectors that will be put on the ellipse. Below is the code I have for all of the vectors that will be drawn. Someone recommended that I use a group element and replace the entire group instead of trying to replace one element at a time. How would I go about using a group element to replace the old input with the new input?

PS: If you want to see the rest of my code just ask. I left out most of it because it is quite lengthy and most of it doesn't pertain to my problem.

```js
function gravityVector(rho1, z1, rho2, z2, rho3, gravRho, gravZ, s, polRad) {
    let svg = document.getElementById('diagram');

    let marker= document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg',
        'marker');
    marker.setAttribute('id', 'triangle');
    marker.setAttribute('viewBox', '0 0 10 10');
    marker.setAttribute('refX', '0');
    marker.setAttribute('refY', '5');
    marker.setAttribute('markerUnits', 'strokeWidth');
    marker.setAttribute('markerWidth', '10');
    marker.setAttribute('markerHeight', '8');
    marker.setAttribute('orient', 'auto');

    let path = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path');
    path.setAttribute('d', `M ${rho2} ${z2} L 210 200 L 200 205 z`);
    path.style.stroke = 'green';
    path.style.strokeWidth = '5px';
    svg.appendChild(path);

    let arrow = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path');
    arrow.setAttribute('d', `M ${rho1},${z1} L ${rho2} ${z2}`);
    arrow.style.stroke = 'black';
    arrow.style.strokeWidth = '2px';
    svg.appendChild(arrow);
    arrow.setAttributeNS('marker-end', 'triangle', 'void');
}

function accelCentVector(rho, z, rho2, z2, rho3, gravRho, gravZ, s, polRad) {
    let svg = document.getElementById('diagram');

    let marker= document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg',
        'marker');
    marker.setAttribute('id', 'triangle');
    marker.setAttribute('viewBox', '0 0 10 10');
    marker.setAttribute('refX', '0');
    marker.setAttribute('refY', '5');
    marker.setAttribute('markerUnits', 'strokeWidth');
    marker.setAttribute('markerWidth', '10');
    marker.setAttribute('markerHeight', '8');
    marker.setAttribute('orient', 'auto');

    let path = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path');
    path.setAttribute('d', `M ${rho3} ${z2} L 210 200 L 200 205 z`);
    path.style.stroke = 'black';
    path.style.strokeWidth = '5px';
    svg.appendChild(path);

    let arrow = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path');
    arrow.setAttribute('d', `M ${rho2},${z2} L ${rho3} ${z2}`);
    arrow.style.stroke = 'red';
    arrow.style.strokeWidth = '2px';
    svg.appendChild(arrow);
    arrow.setAttributeNS('marker-end', 'triangle', 'void');
}

function apperantGravVector(rho, z, rho2, z2, rho3, gravRho, gravZ, s, polRad) {
    let svg = document.getElementById('diagram');

    let marker= document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg',
        'marker');
    marker.setAttribute('id', 'triangle');
    marker.setAttribute('viewBox', '0 0 10 10');
    marker.setAttribute('refX', '0');
    marker.setAttribute('refY', '5');
    marker.setAttribute('markerUnits', 'strokeWidth');
    marker.setAttribute('markerWidth', '10');
    marker.setAttribute('markerHeight', '8');
    marker.setAttribute('orient', 'auto');

    let path = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path');
    path.setAttribute('d', `M ${rho3} ${z2} L 210 200 L 200 205 z`);
    path.style.stroke = 'black';
    path.style.strokeWidth = '5px';
    svg.appendChild(path);

    let arrow = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path');
    arrow.setAttribute('d', `M ${rho},${z} L ${rho3} ${z2}`);
    arrow.style.stroke = 'blue';
    arrow.style.strokeWidth = '2px';
    svg.appendChild(arrow);
    arrow.setAttributeNS('marker-end', 'triangle', 'void');
}
```

Comment: Can you not create a JSFiddle for the same? With HTML including input boxes

Comment: Hi yeshansachithak, I will be honest I am fairly new to JavaScript and have self taught myself everything I know. I do not know what JSFiddle is.

Comment: @Paankey56 https://jsfiddle.net/ lets you create snippets of runnable code, which would help in your case as your javascript has HTML elements referenced

Comment: [this](https://jsfiddle.net/shrys/v0xtn5fa/) would a simple example

Comment: Okay so I am running into problems with using JSFiddle because my code is built to draw the ellipse first and then call the vector functions. I guess to rephrase my question what would I need to add to my code (Given above) so that I can make this group element. My next question would then be how do I then take an old group element and replace it with a new one?